# Printing an Invoice on pre-formatted paper using CSS

Tags: html, css, printing

I have an invoice in html that displays well on the screen.  I want to print it to pre-formatted paper.  the paper has three sections

Header   (fixed height from the Top of the page)

Body    (table made up of  1 - N rows)

Footer  (fixed height  from the bottom of the page)

I have tried using CSS and creating a div using #InvFooter and CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

```css
@page { size:8.5in 11in; margin: 2cm }


#InvFooter {position:absolute;left:50px;bottom:0px;}
```

I Have two problems I can't figure out.

1. How to anchor the footer to the bottom of the printed page.
2. How to limit the Body to a fixed section of the page and overflow into another page if the table has too many rows.

Comment: What do you mean by "pre-formatted paper"? Is the physical paper already partially printed?

Comment: YES exactly.  The color elements of the invoice background are all pre-printed along with a perforation.

Comment: Aha, I see. I think you will have a hard time getting this perfect with CSS. I would advise you to use something along the lines of PDF. CSS & HTML are really better suited as guidelines for how a browser should display your document.. Not for print - sorry.

Comment: I can't *answer* per say, but I'm pretty certain you can't "anchor the footer" to the bottom of the page.  You will have to use a  sandbag" div or a calculated margin between content and footer if you need extra space to push the fotter to the bottom.  Good luck.

Comment: [This may help you](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/).

Comment: Look up a PDF library and use that on your backend. Using HTML/CSS will be a nightmare to get right as it's not designed for this. (NodeJS has an awesome one called PDFkit)

Comment: I have reviewed the link from Sheikh. Thanks it doesn't help though

Comment: Never work with a printer in HTML (shame on me), so I'm not quite sure, but would changing `position:absolute` to `position:fixed` help?

Comment: fixed seems to have the same effect in this case, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: don't, html/css was never intended for printing. Even if you can "hack" absolute sizes to fit your current printer there is no guarantee they will fit the next (or the customer's).

For this reason PDF was invented, to give you want you expect in a printed format (as well as high portability).

By using PDF you are guaranteed to get a fixed (paper-) size.

You will be able to find free pdf-solutions (open source) as well as commercial solutions (such as for example [Dynamic PDF](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/Generate-PDF-.NET.aspx) - and there are many others) that allow you to generate PDF from .Net on the fly/dynamically from server based applications with no dependencies of Adobe products.

Comment: Thanks, in this case the pre-printed forms are only for when we send out invoices.  if the user self bills and prints there own invoice the form is not pre-printed so everything works.  Do the PDF solutions work programmatically (ie i can tell them which DIV

Comment: Yes, it's programmatic. And it's very simple to setup things like invoices etc. I have used it this and more complex things and the resulting files are usually very small in size unless one embed images etc.

Comment: Yeah my server env is Apache over FreeBSD with perl, python, PHP, etc.  I need a solution that's not .net

Answer (score 1):

This is the best compilation of CSS printing techniques I've come across. It has deep links to the W3 standards, excellent examples, 3rd party recommended HTML -> PDF software and a handy JPEG which visializes the 16 different page-margin selectors. It got me started and now I can print over 100+ varying-length project summaries to bring with for executive reviews.

1. The article:
   https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/
2. The handy-dandy page margin JPEG:
   https://media-mediatemple.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/1-image-margin-boxes-large-opt.jpg
3. The demo HTML book:
   https://github.com/rachelandrew/css-for-print/blob/master/book.html
4. The demo print CSS:
   https://github.com/rachelandrew/css-for-print/blob/master/pdf-styles.css

Hope this helps!

EDIT
These might be what you're looking for:

```
.invoice {
   page-break-before: always;
}

.invoice h1.title {
   page-break-after: avoid;
}

.invoice .line-item {
   page-break-inside: avoid;
   page-break-after: auto;
}
```

EDIT
How does formatted paper accommodate multi-page invoices? You must have to print every invoice individually... ugh